# please help me calculate this limit

Tags: calculus, limits

i tried L'hospital but I still cant calculate this, please help!

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}(1+e^{-x})^x$$

Comment: Hint: Let $y = (1 + e^{-x})^x$ and consider $\ln y = x \ln(1 + e^{-x})$ try calculating this limit.

Answer (score 0):

Hint $1$:  $x \ln \left(1+\dfrac{1}{e^x}\right) \sim \dfrac{x}{e^x}$.

Hint $2$: $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{e^x}\right)^x=\left(\left(1+\dfrac{1}{e^x}\right)^{e^x}\right)^{\dfrac{x}{e^x}}$

Comment: from hint 1, isnt it ~ 2x/e^x?

Comment: @Ksdes219. We have $\ln (1 + y) \sim y, y \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

First let's convert the expression into some familiar form: 
$(1+e^{-x})^x=(1+\frac 1{e^x})^{e^x\times xe^{-x}}=\big((1+\frac 1{e^x})^{e^x}\big)^{xe^{-x}}$.

Now since $(1+\frac 1t)^t\to e$ and $te^{-t}\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$, it follows that

$(1+e^{-x})^x=\big((1+\frac 1{e^x})^{e^x}\big)^{xe^{-x}}\to e^0=1$ as $x\to \infty$.